# Table touching the wall

Tags: meaning-in-context

How so I say that a table is in contact with the wall? Should I say that the table is on the wall? [image: table]

Comment: As in the question title: "The table is touching the wall," or "The table is standing/placed against the wall." The table is not *on* the wall though: that would be like a surrealist painting.

Comment: Thanks that's what I wanted to know that I can use the word against there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say the table is *against the wall* or it is *touching the wall*. If you want to emphasise that it is in contact with the wall over the whole of a side as opposed to just a corner being in contact you might say it is flush against the wall.

If you take the table out into the garden and for some reason balance it on a low wall then *on the wall* would be possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the most descriptive word, the word is *abut*. You would say, *The table abuts the wall*. Using *abut* lets me know that the table and the wall share a border (i.e. the table top is touching the wall). It's a usage that most, but not all, people will understand.

*The table touches the wall*, works just as well and is a more common usage.  It is not as descriptive as *abuts*.  A table leg touching the wall would also qualify as *touching*.